# Can't create a url that links to a method in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How do I create a link using link_to, that links to a method in my controller. The link I want to create is something like this:

/meetings/10/contacts/2/send_invite

The send_invite method is in the Contacts controller. I'm unsure what the next step as far as how to setup the routes file. I've tried nesting resources but no luck so far. Also, what is the link to specify in the link_to? I've tried various combinations such as send_invite_path, meeting_contact_send_invite_path, but everything throws an error.

My routes file looks like this:

```
resources :meetings do
    resources :contacts, :only => [:send_invite], :as => :send_invite
end
```

But then when I try to call send_invite_path, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding on austin's answer.  This nesting in config/routes.rb

```
resources :meetings do
    resources :contacts do
      member do
        post :send_invite
      end
    end
  end
```

would give you these routes

```
 send_invite_meeting_contact POST   /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/:id/send_invite(.:format) {:action=>"send_invite", :controller=>"contacts"}
                     meeting_contacts GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"contacts"}
                                      POST   /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"contacts"}
                  new_meeting_contact GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"contacts"}
                 edit_meeting_contact GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"contacts"}
                      meeting_contact GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contacts"}
                                      PUT    /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"contacts"}
                                      DELETE /meetings/:meeting_id/contacts/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"contacts"}
                             meetings GET    /meetings(.:format)                                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"meetings"}
                                      POST   /meetings(.:format)                                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"meetings"}
                          new_meeting GET    /meetings/new(.:format)                                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"meetings"}
                         edit_meeting GET    /meetings/:id/edit(.:format)                             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"meetings"}
                              meeting GET    /meetings/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"meetings"}
                                      PUT    /meetings/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"meetings"}
                                      DELETE /meetings/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"meetings"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the route in your routes.rb file and have setup your routes to be nested. As far as the name goes you can define that in your routes.rb file as well by using `:as => "some_name"` that will allow you to use `link_to some_name_path`.

For more info on routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Specifically on nested resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources